# How to animate rectangle frames?

Tags: c#, image, xna, frame

So I have an image with 2 frames and I want to put it into a rectangle.This image will animate it's frames and will loop them - 1st frame, 2nd frame.

Here's my code:

```
//Create the image
Texture2D image;
//Load, Draw and Update the image in the rectangle
//Load Contnet

protected override void LoadContent()
{
     // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
     image = Content.Load<Texture2D>("image");
}
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
     //Don't know what to write here, but it should make the frames loop
}
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
     //Begin drawing the image
     spriteBatch.Begin();
     spriteBatch.Draw(image, new Rectangle(244, 536, 32, 32), Color.White)
     spriteBatch.End();    
}
```

Can you tell me how to fill in my Update method?

Comment: You would need multiple images I believe. Then you can iterate through the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added these variables above `public Game1()`:

```
    //Sprite Texture
    Texture2D texture;
    //A Timer variable
    float timer = 0f;
    //The interval (300 milliseconds)
    float interval = 300f;
    //Current frame holder (start at 1)
    int currentFrame = 1;
    //Width of a single sprite image, not the whole Sprite Sheet
    int spriteWidth = 32;
    //Height of a single sprite image, not the whole Sprite Sheet
    int spriteHeight = 32;
    //A rectangle to store which 'frame' is currently being shown
    Rectangle sourceRect;
    //The centre of the current 'frame'
    Vector2 origin;
```

Next, in the `LoadContent()` Method:

```
        //Texture load
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("gameGraphics\\Enemies\\Sprite");
```

The `Update()` Method:

```
        //Increase the timer by the number of milliseconds since update was last called
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        //Check the timer is more than the chosen interval
        if (timer > interval)
        {
            //Show the next frame
            currentFrame++;
            //Reset the timer
            timer = 0f;
        }
        //If we are on the last frame, reset back to the one before the first frame (because currentframe++ is called next so the next frame will be 1!)
        currentFrame = currentFrame % 2;
        sourceRect = new Rectangle(currentFrame * spriteWidth, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
        origin = new Vector2(sourceRect.Width / 2, sourceRect.Height / 2);
```

And finally, the `Draw()` Method:

```
        //Texture Draw
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(263, 554), sourceRect,Color.White, 0f, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

**NOTE:** That's the solution that works for me... If anyone finds this answer useful, they should know that their spritesheet must have it's frames aligned *LEFT TO RIGHT* or else the animation won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep an elapsed time counter and then switch at certain intervals. You would also need to have multiple images.

```
const int NUM_IMAGES = 2; // or whatever
Texture2D[] images = new Texture2D[NUM_IMAGES];
double elapsedTime = 0;
int currentFrame = 0;
double frameInterval = .5; // the time, in seconds, between frames

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    // load all of your images. here, I'm assuming that they are numbered.
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IMAGES; i++)
        images[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("image" + i);
}
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // increment elapsed time by the frametime
    elapsedTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    if (elapsedTime >= frameInterval)
    {
        // reset the elapsed time, and then update the frame counter.
        elapsedTime %= frameInterval;
        currentFrame++;
        if (currentFrame >= NUM_IMAGES)
            currentFrame %= NUM_IMAGES;
    }
}
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    // images[currentFrame] to draw the correct frame.
    spriteBatch.Draw(images[currentFrame], new Rectangle(244, 536, 32, 32), Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

Comment: In the Update() method elapsedTime gives "Unreachale code detected" warning. What to do?

Comment: @PowerUser Are you sure that the warning is in the code that I gave you? Because that doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @PowerUser What is this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the following tutorials on `sprite animation`

See:

- [How to do 2D Animation](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/168318-how-to-do-2d-animation-on-xna-part-1/)
- [XNA Animated Sprite](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/194878-xna-animated-sprite/)
- [Spritesheet animation](http://thundernoodle.net/notblog/2011/10/17/how-to-animate-a-sprite-using-a-sprite-sheet-in-xna/)
- [Spritesheet Animation (Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQKF_rqs3e4)
- [Sprite Drawing](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/creatinga2dsprite/CreatingA2DSprite.shtml)